# Cordova, SocialSharing, Send Message to specific person without dialog

Tags: android, cordova, socialshare

I'm using "nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" "https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin" so that i send/share message to any one (through email,facebook, whatsapp, and etc..).

My problem is, i want to auto send messages to specified credential (without showing the  dialog).

I means, once i send a message to person(X) through Whatsapp, i can send to him/her another message (according to some action done in my application).

So, can i store the receiver credential? and how can i get it from  SocialSharing? also how can i send to SocialSharing a specific credential to send to?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use this plugin to do these actions in the background, and I don't think there can or should be a plugin that lets you do that for security reasons.

You are able to use the plugin to send emails/messages to specific recipients (By email address or phone number) but the user will be prompted to complete the action.

You can check the plugin JS source code and look at the function headers here

> https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/www/SocialSharing.js

Good Luck

Comment: I agree with you that it should be fully automatic, but is there any way to be half automatic, like to be setup ( Whatsapp account from mobile number), and on executing the action, to show the post to this account. finally the user will have the option to send or cancel.

Comment: As mentioned in the doc, you can use the plugin's ShareViaWhatsapp method. But your user would still have to choose which WhatsApp contact to share that with.